# PHP ActiveRecord - Could not find the association in model

Tags: php, codeigniter, orm, phpactiverecord

I'm using Codeigniter 2.1.0 along with the [spark to enable PHP ActiveRecord](http://getsparks.org/packages/php-activerecord/versions/HEAD/show) and I am unable to create a many to many association through a lookup table.
Whenever I load the Event model it fails with "Could not find the association eventcategories in model Event" which is a ActiveRecord\HasManyThroughAssociationException

In accordance to [this topic](http://www.phpactiverecord.org/boards/4/topics/226) I've tried updating my source with [this patch](https://github.com/kla/php-activerecord/issues/68) with no effect.

I also followed [this thread](http://www.phpactiverecord.org/boards/4/topics/509) and based my association on the solution given there.

I've ended up with the following sql: http://pastebin.com/ya65VWHC
and the following models: http://pastebin.com/XEDTb6KS

I'm trying to associate one Event with several categories, for example a football game event could have the categories 'sports', 'family' and 'fun'.

Did I miss something fundamental?

Comment: I can add that according to documentation here http://www.phpactiverecord.org/projects/main/wiki/Associations#has_many_through I can't seem to understand what I did wrong.

Comment: It's hard to get a complete picture while needing to click trough to pastebin and all the links you posted, so not an answer, but some point I'd look for is: does it work with the pluralisation? (category/categories)? Can you make a simple example for yourself?

Comment: @Nanne Hi, I've tried plural/singular but it's not it unfortunately.

(I'm a bit puzzled by your example statement, would you like me to compose an example and post it here or simply use it for my own testing of the plural/singular?)

Thnx for having a look at it =)

Comment: Well, both, bot if you have an easy way to give us the problem in here without having to click to pastebin, it's easier to discuss te problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not able to test everything as I don't have a database I could dump your code into (and don't have any test data either  :) ), but your code has some differences with the manual.

If you look at this page: http://www.phpactiverecord.org/projects/main/wiki/Associations#has_many_through

You see three tables, that map like this ( I think )

```
 Order        -> Category   
 Payment      -> Eventcategory 
 User         -> Event
```

A `Category` has multiple `Events` through `Eventcategory`, just like an `Order` has several `Users` through `Payment` in the example. The other way around is defined more basic (a `User` has `Orders`)

Where you have defined 2 "through" relationships, this example only has one in the `Order` class, leaving the `user` with just a `has_many`. That's a big difference I think you might need to address.

Also, I'm not really sure about the `foreign_key` definitions you do in this part:

```
array('events', 'foreign_key' => 'event_id',
              array('through' => 'eventcategories', 'foreign_key' => 'event_id')
```

Iif you've got the default naming scheme you don't need to bother with explicitly naming them.

To fix it, I would start with the order/user/payment example, check that it works for you, and then replace all the parts (carefully :) ) so it becomes your code.

Comment: I spent a full week trying to figure this out, the phpar worked with simple model stuff but not with more complex things.  Thnx to your suggestion to break it down I decided to set up phpar from scratch and that's when I noticed it... *facepalm* *scratches head* I had CIs own active record loaded and for some reason this doe not conflict with basic usage of phpar.  Ah well, thnx, I'll go dance around the office now ;p  btw, you are probably right when it comes to the foreign keys, however everything works now so I won't touch it ;)

Comment: Sounds like it's going the right way again, good luck dancing :)